# SOAP request works on PHP but not working on Ruby (gem: Savon2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, savon

I am trying to perform SOAP request called DoProduct. This method is updating specific product. I looked through WSDL (http://api.istore.pl/#op.idp182160) and found out that I need one Product object and session key.

Everything working perfectly with PHP:

```
    $product = $soap->__soapCall("getProduct", array("sessionId" => $key, "productId" => $id));
    $result = $soap->__soapCall("doProduct", array("sessionId" => $key, "product" => $product));
```

I tried the same approach with Ruby (first get product, then send it back):

```
    product = client.call(:get_product, message: {:session_id => session_key, :product_id => id})
    response = @@client.call(:do_product, message: {:session_id => session_key, :product =>  product.hash[:envelope][:body][:get_product_response][:return]})
```

Ruby version is not working. I am receiving error that one parameter was not send (of course that parameter is there, I've checked hash from first response):

```
    HTTPI POST request to api.istore.pl (net_http)
    SOAP response (status 500)
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S
    OAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>ERR_EMPTY_PRODUCT_TAX</faultcode><faults
    tring></faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

    Savon::SOAPFault: (ERR_EMPTY_PRODUCT_TAX)
    from F:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/savon-2.1.0/lib/savon/response.rb:70:in `raise_soap_and_http_errors!'
    from F:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/savon-2.1.0/lib/savon/response.rb:13:in `initialize'
    from F:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/savon-2.1.0/lib/savon/operation.rb:52:in `new'
    from F:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/savon-2.1.0/lib/savon/operation.rb:52:in `call'
    from F:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/savon-2.1.0/lib/savon/client.rb:38:in `call'
    from C:/Users/Arti/Documents/adgally/v1/app/models/istore.rb:45:in `update_product'
    from (irb):60
    from F:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from F:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from F:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

@EDIT
PHP response (vardump):

```
object(stdClass)[2]
  public 'Id' => int 18028717
  public 'PropertiesIds' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'ImagesIds' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 22573396
  public 'Currency' => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'Id' => int 1
      public 'Symbol' => string 'PLN' (length=3)
      public 'Round' => boolean false
      public 'Active' => boolean true
      public 'Rate' => float 1
  public 'Tax' => 
    object(stdClass)[4]
      public 'Id' => int 23
      public 'Name' => string '23%' (length=3)
      public 'Rate' => float 23
  public 'Symbol' => string ' ' (length=1)
  public 'Promotion' => boolean false
  public 'Wholesale' => boolean false
  public 'New' => boolean false
  public 'DeliveryTimeLength' => int 0
  public 'DeliveryTimeLengthPeriod' => string 'D' (length=1)
  public 'Producer' => null
  public 'PKWiU' => null
  public 'Active' => boolean true
  public 'Netto' => float 11.38
  public 'Brutto' => float 14
  public 'PromotionNetto' => float 0
  public 'PromotionBrutto' => float 0
  public 'WholesaleNetto' => float 0
  public 'WholesaleBrutto' => float 0
  public 'FirstPage' => int 0
  public 'Sequence' => int 18028717
  public 'Unit' => 
    object(stdClass)[5]
      public 'Id' => int 1
      public 'Symbol' => string 'szt.' (length=4)
  public 'PostSize' => string 'A' (length=1)
  public 'SortProperty' => string 'N' (length=1)
  public 'MainCategory' => 
    object(stdClass)[6]
      public 'Id' => int 34
      public 'Name' => string 'Odzież, Obuwie, Dodatki' (length=24)
  public 'Names' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[7]
          public 'Symbol' => string 'pl' (length=2)
          public 'Name' => string 'Bluzka testowa 2' (length=16)
  public 'Description' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[8]
          public 'Symbol' => string 'pl' (length=2)
          public 'Description' => string 'asdsad' (length=6)
  public 'HTMLDescription' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[9]
          public 'Symbol' => string 'pl' (length=2)
          public 'Description' => string 'asdasdas' (length=8)
  public 'MetaKeywords' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[10]
          public 'Symbol' => string 'pl' (length=2)
          public 'Description' => string 'bluzka, jesień, fajna' (length=22)
  public 'CategoriesIds' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 1695922
  public 'BindingProducts' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'Availability' => string 'A' (length=1)
  public 'Quality' => string 'N' (length=1)
  public 'Variants' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[11]
          public 'ShopProductPropertyValueIds' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public 'Quantity' => float 1
          public 'WarehouseId' => int 20666112
          public 'Available' => boolean true
  public 'Weight' => float 0
  public 'Blocked' => boolean false
  public 'HideExternalOpinions' => boolean false
  public 'Width' => int 0
  public 'Height' => int 0
  public 'Deep' => int 0
  public 'InpostEnabled' => boolean false
  public 'Available' => boolean true
  public 'Ean' => null
```

Ruby Savon response.to_hash object (sorry for formatting, but I dont have any idea how to format it from console properly): http://pastie.org/7065887

Additionaly ruby response.to_json (formatting is better):

```
{
   "get_product_response":{
      "return":{
         "id":"18028717",
         "properties_ids":{
            "@soap_enc:array_type":"xsd:int[0]",
            "@xsi:type":"ns1:ArrayOfint"
         },
         "images_ids":{
            "item":"22573396",
            "@soap_enc:array_type":"xsd:int[1]",
            "@xsi:type":"ns1:ArrayOfint"
         },
         "currency":{
            "id":"1",
            "symbol":"PLN",
            "round":false,
            "active":true,
            "rate":"1",
            "@xsi:type":"ns1:Currency"
         },
         "tax":{
            "id":"23",
            "name":"23%",
            "rate":"23",
            "@xsi:type":"ns1:Tax"
         },
         "symbol":{
            "@xsi:type":"xsd:string"
         },
         "promotion":false,
         "wholesale":false,
         "new":false,
         "delivery_time_length":"0",
         "delivery_time_length_period":"D",
         "producer":null,
         "pk_wi_u":null,
         "active":true,
         "netto":"11.38",
         "brutto":"14",
         "promotion_netto":"0",
         "promotion_brutto":"0",
         "wholesale_netto":"0",
         "wholesale_brutto":"0",
         "first_page":"0",
         "sequence":"18028717",
         "unit":{
            "id":"1",
            "symbol":"szt.",
            "@xsi:type":"ns1:Unit"
         },
         "post_size":"A",
         "sort_property":"N",
         "main_category":{
            "id":"34",
            "name":"Odzieu017c, Obuwie, Dodatki",
            "@xsi:type":"ns1:MainCategory"
         },
         "names":{
            "item":{
               "symbol":"pl",
               "name":"Bluzka testowa 2",
               "@xsi:type":"ns1:TranslationName"
            },
            "@soap_enc:array_type":"ns1:TranslationName[1]",
            "@xsi:type":"ns1:ArrayOfTranslationName"
         },
         "description":{
            "item":{
               "symbol":"pl",
               "description":"asdsad",
               "@xsi:type":"ns1:TranslationDescription"
            },
            "@soap_enc:array_type":"ns1:TranslationDescription[1]",
            "@xsi:type":"ns1:ArrayOfTranslationDescription"
         },
         "html_description":{
            "item":{
               "symbol":"pl",
               "description":"asdasdas",
               "@xsi:type":"ns1:TranslationDescription"
            },
            "@soap_enc:array_type":"ns1:TranslationDescription[1]",
            "@xsi:type":"ns1:ArrayOfTranslationDescription"
         },
         "meta_keywords":{
            "item":{
               "symbol":"pl",
               "description":"bluzka, jesieu0144, fajna",
               "@xsi:type":"ns1:TranslationDescription"
            },
            "@soap_enc:array_type":"ns1:TranslationDescription[1]",
            "@xsi:type":"ns1:ArrayOfTranslationDescription"
         },
         "categories_ids":{
            "item":"1695922",
            "@soap_enc:array_type":"xsd:int[1]",
            "@xsi:type":"ns1:ArrayOfint"
         },
         "binding_products":{
            "@soap_enc:array_type":"xsd:int[0]",
            "@xsi:type":"ns1:ArrayOfint"
         },
         "availability":"A",
         "quality":"N",
         "variants":{
            "item":{
               "shop_product_property_value_ids":{
                  "@soap_enc:array_type":"xsd:int[0]",
                  "@xsi:type":"ns1:ArrayOfint"
               },
               "quantity":"1",
               "warehouse_id":"20666112",
               "available":true,
               "@xsi:type":"ns1:ProductVariant"
            },
            "@soap_enc:array_type":"ns1:ProductVariant[1]",
            "@xsi:type":"ns1:ArrayOfProductVariant"
         },
         "weight":"0",
         "blocked":false,
         "hide_external_opinions":false,
         "width":"0",
         "height":"0",
         "deep":"0",
         "inpost_enabled":false,
         "available":true,
         "ean":null,
         "@xsi:type":"ns1:Product"
      }
   }
}
```

Does any one could give me any hint?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the error `ERR_EMPTY_PRODUCT_TAX`?

Comment: debug? something crazy like `raise params.inspect` in controller method should return you request params in soap response

Comment: i'm sorry, but just taking that hash and reusing it will probably not work.

Comment: @rubiii, so what should I try? Build own XML document and pass it to call method?

Comment: @Arti yes, i would take the arguments from the response and construct a new request message from the values you need. you raised a good point though.

Answer (score 0):

According to the SOAP response, you are in fact missing a parameter the SOAP service is expecting.

I notice with the PHP version you are just sending the entire product object, but in the Ruby version you are digging into the response hash.

Can you inspect 'product' in both versions and post the response here?

Comment: I've added responses to my question. I'd be very appreciated for your help.